# Spark kubernetes java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RetrieveSparkAppConfig$

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I'm trying to run a pySpark job against nodes in a Kubernetes cluster, but when I try to create a pyspark.sql.SparkSession the logs get flooded with the error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedClusterMessages$RetrieveSparkAppConfig$; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -3781927201751596568, local class serialVersionUID = 2700058563611836699
```

I am using the pre-built version of spark 2.4.6 with hadoop2.7, and the docker image used by the nodes is built using the following command, executed from the pre-built distribution folder:

```
/bin/docker-image-tool.sh -p kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile -r {repo} -t {tag} build
```

The machine issuing the pySpark jobs runs ubuntu 18.04 with the OpenJDK 8 JDK and pySpark 2.4.6 installed via pip. The SPARK_HOME environment variable is set to the same spark distribution folder from where the docker image was built, and the JAVA_HOME is correctly set.

Note that no extra jars were added to the distribution.

I understand that this is usually caused by a version mismatch, but I cannot figure out what's mismatching here.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting spark job from docker/kubernetes requires couple of things:

- Check python version and jar versions in your local machine that you submit Spark job and in the Spark cluster. Their versions should match.
- Define python virtual environment and install same versions of packages with the cluster.
- If it's necessary, define `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` environments.
- Do not forget that `spark.driver.blockManager.port` and `spark.driver.port` of your local machine should be reachable by the spark cluster.

These list may go on depending on the infrastructure.